# Find most recent fileS, return the last x number of files IF made within a minute of each other

Tags: vba, search, excel, dir

The situation I'm in is the following:
I need to return the path of the most recent fileS in a folder. The number of files that I need to return is specified by "**numberOfFiles**" and is in descending order from most recent.
E.g,

```
   File1.doc - Last modified at 8:42:00 PM
   File2.doc - Last modified at 8:43:00 PM
   File3.doc - Last modified at 8:44:00 PM
```

numberOfFiles = 2, should return an array of;

```
   File3.doc's path
   File2.doc's path
```

This much is working, with the code below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileSpec As String

    Dim MostRecentFile As String
    Dim MostRecentDate As Date
    Dim Directory As String
    Dim resultArray() As String
    Dim groupedArray() As String

    Dim fileCounter As Integer
    Dim groupedArrayCounter As Integer
    Dim resultArrayCounter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim numberOfFiles As Integer: numberOfFiles = 2

    Directory = "C:\Test\"
    FileSpec = "File*.doc"
    If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then Directory = Directory & "\"

    fileCounter = 0
    FileName = Dir(Directory & FileSpec, 0)
    If FileName <> "" Then
        MostRecentFile = FileName
        MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            If FileDateTime(Directory & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
                 MostRecentFile = FileName
                 MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
                 ReDim Preserve resultArray(fileCounter)
                 resultArray(fileCounter) = FileName
                 fileCounter = fileCounter + 1
             End If
             FileName = Dir()
        Loop
    End If

    groupedArrayCounter = 0
    resultArrayCounter = UBound(resultArray)
    ReDim groupedArray(numberOfFiles - 1)
    For i = numberOfFiles To 1 Step -1
        groupedArray(groupedArrayCounter) = resultArray(resultArrayCounter)
        groupedArrayCounter = groupedArrayCounter + 1
        resultArrayCounter = resultArrayCounter - 1
    Next i

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

One last requirement has been put on at the last minute, and I'm not sure how I can achieve it. While I need to be able to return **numberOfFiles** amount of the most recent files (which works), I must only do so if the files are modified within 60 seconds or less of each other (This also needs to be done in descending order from the most recent - in this example, File3). For example;

```
   If file 2 is made within 60 seconds of file 3, add it to the final array
   If file 1 is made within 60 seconds of file 2, add it to the final array
   Etc until there are no more files or we have exceeded numberOfFiles
```

Help greatly appreciated

Edit:

I know this can be done somehow using DateDiff("s", var1, var2), I'm just not entirely sure how the logic will work going in descending order starting from the uBound of my array

Comment: I suppose you can extract the modified time of each file, then you can calculate the difference of modified time between the files, isn't it?

Comment: compare the `datediff("n", fileOne, fileTwo) < 60`, where `n` stands for minutes

Comment: @sam092 is right. Just loop through each file and store both filename and date of last modification. Then sort based on date of last modification and test on that (you'll find many ways to do that on stackoverflow)
A date in excel is nothing else than a number that iterates by 1 everyday. So (Date1 - Date3)*24*3600 gives you the difference in seconds, and it also means you can sort based on the date too